# Compiling one line instead of another in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a program that has a reference to a file on our network drive ("PricingMaster.omas"), but when I'm beta testing I use a different file ("PricingMasterBetaTest.omas").  Currently I manually change the string from one to the other.

So:

```
File masterFile = new File("g:/DataTeam", "PricingMasterBetaTest.omas");
```

Becomes:

```
File masterFile = new File("g:/DataTeam", "PricingMaster.omas");
```

This actually happens in a couple places in a couple files so, as you can probably imagine, sometimes I forget and my users end up quite confused.  So I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that I can determine which string is used depending on what I'm compiling it for?

I've tried asking Google, but I lack the knowledge to phrase the question properly.  In my mind the psuedo code looks something like this:

```
@CompileDebug
File masterFile = new File("g:/DataTeam", "PricingMasterBetaTest.omas");

@CompileRelease
File masterFile = new File("g:/DataTeam", "PricingMaster.omas");
```

I am doing this project in Eclipse, so perhaps it's a trick that Eclipse can help me with?  I'm also not opposed to doing this in Ant if it's possible.  Sorry, I know I'm being a bit vague (or dense), I'm just not doing well with my Google-fu today.

Comment: You could use an if statement. Is that not an option here ?

Comment: The usual method for injecting data driven by configuration is to use a properties file that has different values depending on your configuration. Essentially, your jar deployment would contain a properties file with the file and path you want to use for testing.

Comment: @Hunter I was really hoping to make it a compile time decision instead of a run-time decision.  Are there compile time ifs?  I'm still kind of new...

Comment: @JayCarr No, but why would it need to be a compile time decision? Is a single if-statement at run-time really going to cost you much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically run into this problem because you're *hard-coding* your strings. Ideally, one should *externalise* such strings into a `.properties` file where you could then point to a different file without re-compiling the program.

And this isn't all that hard to do. *Eclipse* comes with a built-in `Externalise Strings` feature that handles all the Java code for you. Anything else would simply be hacking around the problem.

Eclipse's `Source` menu:

[image: Externalise Strings]

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd redefine the problem, and pass the filename in on the command line:

```
java -Dfile=PrixingMaster.omas -jar foo.jar
```

Or use something like an [option parsing library](https://github.com/wibidata/odiago-common-flags):

```
@Option(name='file')
private String filename;
```

Or an options file, or a flag, or something based on the current machine or user, etc.

Comment: Or at the very list create a final class with a `public static final String CONSTANT` where you can change you file in *one* single place

Comment: Mmm, both are good ideas, I will admit.  I've been thinking of doing something like this, but I would prefer to just tell the compiler which one to take depending on the situation...  I'll keep this in mind though just incase it can't be done.

Comment: @JayCarr I think it's pretty clear what direction you should take from every single one of the answers. I don't understand the reluctance at all.

Comment: @Dave Eh, it's nothing personal.  I just had it in my head that I wanted to do it differently, and it takes me some time to lose that mental inertia, if you will.  I decided to go with externalizing the strings in Eclipse as described by Ravi.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, putting parameters like the name of a file into the code is bad practice, even if it is done at compile time, as you suggest.

A better solution would be to actually parameterize your application. Is it a simple console application? Then you can just add the file name as console parameter and read it in you main method.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the string in `Constants` class so you don't have repeated strings all over the place.

```
public class Constant {
    public static final String FILE_PATH= "";
}
```

---

Another option would be to put this string into a properties file and load it when the application starts. Since you have two builds (debug and release) you probably have two build/run scripts. You should also have two properties files: `testconfig.properies` and `config.properties` that contain different file paths. Each should be included in the executable jar (or however you deploy the app) depending if it's debug or release.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Config class and you can have a static variable called networkDrive in it.

```
public class Config{
     //public static String networkDrive = "PricingMasterBetaTest.omas"; //DEBUG
     public static String networkDrive = "PricingMaster.omas"; //RELEASE
}
```

When you want use "PricingMasterBetaTest.omas", just comment out DEBUG line and comment RELEASE line.

```
File masterFile = new File("g:/DataTeam", Config.networkDrive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the file name in a properties file, and use a resource bundle for it.

Where do you store your test classes?  Do you have parallel hierarchies like the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` common in Maven projects, or `src` and `test` as you might have in Ant and Eclipse?  If you do, then use identically named properties files in corresponding locations, and make sure that the test hierarchy precedes the src hierarchy in the source folder list or the Ant class paths.  I think the file that appears first wins in class paths.  You have to do things by hand with Ant, have to play around with options in Eclipse, or do things pretty automatically with Maven.

## ANT

So, have your hierarchies be

- src

  - com

    - jaycarr

      - omas

        - pricing.properties
- test

  - com

    - jaycarr

      - omas

        - pricing.properties

And define classpaths:

```
<path id="lib.classpath">
    ...
</path>

<!--  Additional libraries for testing. -->
<path id="testlib.classpath">
    ...
</path>

<path id="compile.classpath">
    ...
    <pathelement location="src"/>
    <path refid="lib.classpath"/>
</path>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <path refid="testlib.classpath"/>
    <pathelement location="test"/>
    <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
</path>
```

Test with the test classpath, so the test/../pricing.properties wins.

## Maven

Just use

- src

  - main

    - java

      - com

        - jaycarr

          - omas

            - pricing.properties
  - test

    - java

      - com

        - jaycarr

          - omas

            - pricing.properties

You're done.

## Eclipse

This is the hardest.  I'm not sure how to exclude test libraries and folders from the main build.  This isn't a complete answer.

You could put your tests in a new project that depends on your main one.  This will keep you from deploying your tool with junit.jar by accident.